# Can't find/update an object in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

My collection looks like this: (Don't ask me why it's an array inside of a collection)

```
const postsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    posts: {type: Array},
})
```

I want to find a document in it and I tried this:

```
Posts.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
                'posts': { _id: new ObjectId(req.query.postId), }
            }
        }
])
```

And this:

```
Posts.find({
   posts: {
        $elemMatch: { "_id" : new ObjectId(req.query.postId) }
   }
})
```

And this:

```
Posts.findOne({
     'posts._id': new ObjectId(req.query.postId)
})
```

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is what I mentioned above. I have an array in a collection, where I want to find a document, but I can't do it. the req.query.id is received from the request, it just can't find it and I don't know how/why

Comment: So what do you expect it to return, and what is it returning instead? The query you should seems like it should work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vQ_TZ93oNeU

Comment: I expect it to return the document which has that id, not the whole array

Answer (score 0):

```
const { postId } = req.query.postId;
const result = await Posts.findOne({ _id: postId })
```

*If you use async function you can put await else you can do .then method to get the result and avoid the await keyword*

Answer (score 0):

to help you I can show you this code I made in typescript.

use the await to retrieve the give and put your function in async

the model (user job is the array

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema<UserInterface>({
    discordId: {required: true, type: "string"},
    username: {required: true, type: "string"},
    githubName: {required: true, type: "string"},
    userJob: [String],
    paypal: {type: "string", default: null},
    commandCount: {type: "number", default: 0},
    commandInProgress: {type: "number", default: 0},
})
```

the get and update

```js
let job = "BigLol"
let result = await userModel.findOne({discordId: "0000022"});
result.userJob.push(job)
result.save();
```